# Is there a way to mirror my screen to a PC with sound?

Tags: screen-sharing, audio-recording, screencast

I just want to make app reviews in video. Some of these app's eventually will be games, so if I can mirror video to my PC and capture the audio at the same time it would be great. So, my question is : Is there a way to mirror my screen to a PC with sound?

Comment: I haven't tested them but they claim to come with audio support too. Check them out [here](http://screen.bbqdroid.org/) and [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.awindinc.sphone2tv&hl=en). Can't comment about Audio support from [this](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/).

Comment: As far I know ....you can do it on Windows 10 with connect app but I am using Windows 7 on very outdated version of pc and hardware...so I am also looking for the answers..... I look for some apps like mirrorgo , Apower mirror etc...but that didn't work for me....the audio input from internal source do not work.....actually there is no sound at all when the Android screen is casted..... I don't know why it's not working..... Change your audio source in developer options to usb.... It might work

Answer (score 1):

install "Scrcpy" in linux / need to start adb connection  first either usb or over the IP.

Comment: `scrcpy` has no audio channel through USB yet. It is under research for Android 10+ devices: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/14 and https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/1407

Comment: 2023 update, `scrcpy` since version 2.x now has support for audio forwarding on Android 11+, see [link](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/doc/audio.md) for details

Answer (score 0):

Download third party software **Wondershare MirroGo**. It works great (Not promoting).
Some instructions to follow:-
 - You can download Mirror Go from [Here](https://drfone.wondershare.com/android-mirror.html)
 - After downloading and installing, Enable your phone's USB
    debugging, see here -  [How to enable USB Debugging.](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm)
 - Simply connect your phone with USB and accept the [adb authorization
    request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPh73.png) pop-ups on screen and you're done.
Main advantages of this software is that:
 - You can render your phone's screen on Desktop/Laptop.
 - You can play games/movies/songs through MirrorGo.
 - You can control your phone via MirrorGo through Mouse/Keyboard.
 - You can record your screen via MirrorGo during the live view of your phone in your laptop/desktop.
You can Also use MirroGo with MobileGO ( an advanced software to backup your whole phone with one click and tons of features and works for Iphone too).

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no audio/sound mirroring