# How do I record audio of an application when sharing the screen on Zoom Android?

Tags: audio, zoom-cloud-meetings

I am using Android's Zoom application to screen share with other people. They all see my screens are fine, but the audio from the application is mute.

I can mute and unmute the hardware microphone (it picks up the ambient noises or my speech), but the sound from the Android application itself (e.g. video playing, system sounds, youtube video, etc) is non-existent.

In the desktop version of Zoom, when you screen share, there is a checkbox for sharing system sounds or the screen you are sharing, but I don't see such an option with the Android version.

How do I record audio of an application when sharing the screen on Zoom (Android)?

I'm using Samsung ActiveTab 2 (on Samsung's Android 9 I think).

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/103589/is-there-a-way-to-mirror-my-screen-to-a-pc-with-sound
this is not zoom but might be an option for you